# Proving a function has a convergent subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that

$Y_n = tan(n)$ has a convergent subsequence

Thanks for any help provided

Not asking for direct answer, but strong hints/the solution would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a natural number $n_1 \in (0, \pi/3]$. Then choose a natural number $n_2 \in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3]$. Having chosen a natural number $n_k \in ((k-1)\pi/3, k\pi/3]$, choose a natural number $n_{k+1}\in (k\pi/3, (k+1)\pi/3]$. This gives a sequence $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \cdots$ of natural numbers such that $\tan(n_k)$ is bounded. Use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and the fact that a subseqeunce of a subsequence is a subsequence to deduce that $\tan(n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $|\tan n|\gt 10$ then $|\tan(n+1)|\lt 10$.

Comment: In previous problems I used the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem to show that a bounded series has a convergent subsequence. Would this be useful for this problem at all?

Comment: Yes, I left out mention of Bolzano-Weierstrass in order to not make it too big a hint. But after proving the fact mentioned in the hint, or something like it, we use B-W. The hint shows that our sequence has an infinite subsequence with terms between $10$ and $10$.